# Why am I getting a ReferenceError: 'x' is not defined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I'm working on a site using the MEAN stack, I've got a helper js function which was working fine but now is giving me ReferenceError errors.  I know this isn't elegant but this is my function:

```
module.exports.formatDatePickerDate = function(dt) {
if( dt !== undefined ) {
var ys = dt[date][year];
var ms = '0' + dt[date][month].slice(-2);
var ds = '0' + dt[date][day].slice(-2);
var cs = ys + '-' + ms + '-' + ds;
console.log(cs);
return cs;
} else {
return undefined;
}
}
```

it's being passed an object that looks like this:

> { date: { year: 2017, month: 7, day: 20 },   jsdate:
>   '2017-07-19T23:00:00.000Z',   formatted: '20/07/2017',   epoc:
>   1500505200 }

If anyone can give me some pointers i'd be very appreciative.  The only thing that I've knowingly changed with it since it was last working is adding the if statement to catch if a date field hasn't been completed.

Comment: On which line do you get the error ? You do not have an `x` variable

Comment: Apart from the missing `x`, there are a lot of undefined variables in your code, like `date` and `year` in `var ys = dt[date][year];`.

Comment: Probably *date*, *year*, *month* and *day* are undefined...

Comment: Thanks all, i'm such an idiot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use quotes to access the properties of an object.

```
var ys = dt['date']['year'];
```